# WordPress Ajax Filter Issue: Custom Code Not Filtering Posts Correctly on Different Pages"

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem regarding Ajax filtering. I need to modify the PHP Ajax code for custom filtering in WordPress on different pages while using the same Ajax code. For example, I have two pages with the same code and Ajax shortcode: the Pre-Festival page and the Street Festival page. Inside each page, I'm using a shortcode [EVENTS_DECK_SC CAT_ID='98'] for Pre-Festival and [EVENTS_DECK_SC CAT_ID='101'] for Street Festival. When I'm on the Pre-Festival page and use the filter dropdown to select a category, it correctly displays the relevant posts. However, when I'm on the Street Festival page and use the filter, it shows the Pre-Festival posts instead of the Street Festival posts. and this is my code

```
<?php
// **************************** EVENTS SHORTCODE ****************************
add_shortcode('events_deck_sc', 'events_deck_fn');
function events_deck_fn($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat_id' => '',
    ), $atts);
    
    ob_start();
    
    $event_categories = get_field('select_event_categories', 'option');

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );

    if (!empty($atts['cat_id'])) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $atts['cat_id'],
            ),
        );
    }
    
    $events_cat = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'portfolio_category',
        'include'      => $event_categories,
        'orderby' => 'name',
    );
    $portfolio_tag = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'portfolio_tag',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hide_empty'  => false
    );

    $events = new WP_Query($args);
    $portfolio_categories = get_terms($events_cat);
    $portfolio_tags = get_terms($portfolio_tag);
    ?>

    <section class="events-deck-wrapper">
        <div class="events-filter">
            <div class="event-row">
                <div class="event-category-filter">
                    <form id="events_cat_form">
                        <select id="events-cat-filter-dropdown" onChange="getEventsResults()">
                            <option value="all">Event Category</option>
                            <?php foreach( $portfolio_categories as $event_cat ) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $event_cat->slug; ?>"><?= $event_cat->name ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>                  
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="events-tag-filter">
                    <form id="events_tag_form">
                        <select id="events-tag-filter-dropdown" onChange="getEventsResults()"> 
                            <option value="all" >Event Type</option>
                            <?php foreach( $portfolio_tags as $pt ) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $pt->slug; ?>"><?= $pt->name ?></option> 
                            <?php endforeach; ?>                  
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="events-deck--content" class="postgrid-item-container"> 
            <?php
            if ($events->have_posts()) :
                while ($events->have_posts()) : $events->the_post();
                    get_template_part('template-parts/event', 'card');
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else :
                echo 'No events found.';
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getEventsResults() {
            jQuery('#events-deck--content').html("Loading...");
            jQuery.get(
                '<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>',
                {
                    'action' : 'events_filter_fn',
                    'category' : jQuery('#events-cat-filter-dropdown').val(),
                    'tag' : jQuery('#events-tag-filter-dropdown').val(),
                }
                ).done(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                if (response['success']) {
                    jQuery('#events-deck--content').html(response['data']);
                    jQuery('#events-deck--content').append(response['data']['output']);
                }    
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}

// **************************** EVENTS AJAX FILTER ****************************
add_action('wp_ajax_events_filter_fn', 'events_filter_fn');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_events_filter_fn', 'events_filter_fn');
function events_filter_fn(){
   
    ob_start();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );
    
    $filter = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category', // Change this to your actual taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'pre-festival-events-2023',
        )
    );
    
    if (isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] != 'all') {
        $filter[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category', // Change this to your actual taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['category']
        );
    }

    if (isset($_GET['tag']) && $_GET['tag'] != 'all') {
        $filter[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['tag']
        );
    }

    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND', 
        ...$filter
    );
    
    $post_args = new WP_Query( $args );
 
    if ($post_args->have_posts()) :
        while ($post_args->have_posts()) : $post_args->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/event', 'card');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    echo wp_send_json_success(
        array(
            'output' => ob_get_clean(),
        )
    );
    wp_die();
}

function convert_slug($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your AJAX calling code as well, please? You seem to parametrize the category and the tag but not the actual tag terms. How do you intend on passing these in from the shortcode to the page and then to the AJAX JavaScript code?

Comment: i edit the code

Comment: I still don't see the AJAX JS (frontend) code. Can you add it please?

Comment: you can see now.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Your query contains the `'pre-festival-events-2023'` term, which means that all posts will be filtered to it only, no?

Comment: I have 2 pages street festival and pre-festival. each of them has a different post. if in pre-festival and I use the dropdown and choose filter the result is correct. but if I'm in the street festival and use the dropdown and choose filter the result is under the pre-festival. but 2 pages have the same shortcode. is there something wrong with the code?